# AttributeError at /hajj/scratchcard/2/ - 'function' object has no attribute 'objects' -

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a model named ScartchCard with I have input PIn and Serial Number into. However, User will enter the PIN and Serial Number into form. I want my view to confirm that the Serial and pins are tally or exit in the Database. Then, the user can proceed to another page.

models.py

```
class ScratchCard(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='card', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    serial = models.CharField('Serial Number', max_length=50)
    pin = models.PositiveIntegerField("Card PIN")
    is_used = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

views.py

```
 def ScratchCard(request, user_id):

        template_name = 'scratch_card.html'

        if request.method == "POST":
            pin = request.POST.get('pin')
            serial = request.POST.get('serial')
            print(pin)
            print(serial)

            person = ScratchCard.objects.get(pin=pin)
            print(person)



    return render(request, template_name)][1]
```

scratch_card.html

```
 <form method="post" class="form-element" novalidate>
                    {% csrf_token %}             



                    <label for="pin">PIN No:</label>
              <input type="text" name="pin" placeholder="pin">
    <label for="serial">Serial No:</label>
              <input type="text" name="serial" placeholder="serial">
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Login">




            </form>
```

Comment: You named a function `ScratchCard`, so that overrides the reference to your model.

Comment: I think your view function and model name are the same, change them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of your function is the same as the name of your model. This thus means that the `ScratchCard` in your function refers to your function, *not* to your model anymore.

You can fix it by renaming the function to `scratch_card` for example:

```
def scratch_card(request, user_id):
    template_name = 'scratch_card.html'
    if request.method == "POST":
        pin = request.POST.get('pin')
        serial = request.POST.get('serial')
        print(pin)
        print(serial)

        person = ScratchCard.objects.get(pin=pin)
        print(person)
    return render(request, template_name)
```

This is also advised by the [PEP-8 style guidelines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Classes are written in *`CamelCase`*, whereas functions and attributes are usually written in *`lower_case_with_underscores`*.

You will need to update your `urls.py` as well, since renaming the function also implies rewriting the identifiers that otherwise point to a non-existing view. In fact these URLS will then point to the model object instead.